# Meaning of the character sequence after an Entity's name

Tags: implementation-details, entity

*Mathematica* can interpret an entity when you type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>, like this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then we'll get an entity

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We can get the `InputForm`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You will get a canonical name `"MaoZedong::ksc4t"`. I think the sequence after `::` is a hindrance for the user to use such entities. **What is its meaning?**

If we leave it off from the entity's name, we retrieve an `UnknownEntity`:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So the postfix of `ksc4t` has a specific meaning: how to find it somewhere?

---

I find very many entities that have such a strange sequence in their full name:

> type={"WritingScript","USCongressionalDistrict","Tunnel","TropicalStorm","Stadium","Ship","ReserveLand","Shipwreck","Reef","River","PreservationStatus","PersonTitle","Person","OilField","Neighborhood","NetworkService","MusicWorkRecording","MusicWork","MusicAlbum","Museum","MusicAct","MusicAlbumRelease","Movie","Mine","LibrarySystem","LibraryBranch","Lake","Forest","Food","FictionalCharacter","Dinosaur","Desert","Dam","Concept","Company","Cemetery","Cave","Canal","Building","Beach","Bridge","AmusementPark","Airline","Airport","Alphabet","AmusementParkRide","Artwork"};

You can get its entity

```
CanonicalName[RandomEntity[#]] & /@ type
(*You can get its entity*)
```

But as you can see, other entities of the same kind may have no postfix sometimes:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: No. It doesn't mean anything. It's just a hash of something from somewhere to ensure that the value is unique. It can also change basically without warning.

Comment: @Searke How about [this opion?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/oUe2W.png)

Comment: I don't understand what that means. It doesn't make sense. Where is that from? 
My statement is all you need to know about this. There's no mystery. No secret. No magic. It's just a hash to make the string unique.

Comment: The picture is my part of post.I mean the string followed a string unique make me hard to use `Entity`.Such as you should input `Entity["Person","MaoZedong::ksc4t"]` in `Mathematica` to generate a `Entity` `Mathematica` can identify.Actually we all don't know the string unique,but if you don't include it such as you input `Entity["Person","MaoZedong"]`,you will get a `UnknownEntity`.

Comment: As Searke mentioned, the string in the second argument of `Entity` needs to be unique. For instance for the type `"Person"`, this allows to differentiate between homonyms: consider `Entity["Person", "HarrisonFord::y8237"]` and `Entity["Person", "HarrisonFord::kn5xw"]`. Using `Ctrl`+`=` as you mentioned is probably the best way to go.

Comment: @Xavier Actually I'm aware of it.But the Searke don't understand what I say still maybe.English frustrate me.:)And I think you should make the comment as an answer.I think it can help some people.Do you think we can find the second `Mao Zedong`?

Comment: @yode The fact that there is additional information in the string does not necessarily mean that there exists an homonym in Wolfram data I think. It could be that `Mao Zedong` is used for another type of entities. Consider for instance: `Entity["MusicAlbum", "Gravity::2y878"]` and `Entity["Movie", "Gravity::6898h"]`. There is also the possibility that `"MaoZedong::ksc4t"` is the only instance of `Mao Zedong` for all types, and the string `ksc4t` is there for future distinction if needed.

Comment: @yode About the question of how to find automatically other instances of a same "short" name in different types (say, `"Gravity"`), I do not know if there exists a way. Perhaps someone more familiar with `Entity` will be able to provide one.

Comment: @Xavier Anyway,thanks for your exploration.:)

Comment: Or `Interpreter["Person"]["Mao Zedong"]`

Comment: @BobHanlon Beautiful solution.:)